# Passing JS variable(array) to Laravel Controller

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have a project using JS and Laravel.

In blade.php I have a list of items with checkboxes, the list I retrieve from the external database based on its status. I need to be able to select some items and by one click change its status (for example "archive").

```
  function getSelected(){
  let selected = new Array()
  let tblTickets = document.getElementById('tblTickets')
  let checked = tblTickets.getElementsByTagName("input")
  for (let i = 0; i < checked.length; i++) {
    if (checked[i].checked) {
        selected.push(checked[i].value)
    }
 }
  if (selected.length > 0) {
   let nr = selected.map(Number)
    console.log(nr)

 }
}
```

Here is my JS code which gives me the array of numbers (id(s)- primary keys of selected items)

In web.php I created named route for update:

```
Route::put("/tickets/update", [TicketsController::class, 'update'])->name('tickets.update');
```

In ticketsController I have following function:

```
public function update($ids){
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $tickets = DB::connection('secondDB')->table('ticket')
            ->join('ticket_status', 'id', '=', 'status_id')
            ->where('id', '=', $id)
            ->update(['name' => 'Closed']);
    }
     $route= route('tickets.update');
    return view('tickets', [
        'tickets' => $tickets, 
        'route' => $route

}
```

(its second connected external database, so I cannot make Model for it, so I white query manually)

In tickets.blade I added script so I can access route variable in JS

```
 <script>
  const ticketsApi = @json($route);
 </script>
```

My question is - how to POST an array of ids of checked tickets to the "update" function in Controller using the route I pass in blade.php?
(I know I can loop as well in JS, but if I'll have 1000 tickets, I gonna need to POST 1000 requests, I find it more effective to loop in PHP).

this one doesn't work

```
 fetch(route,
    {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(numbers)
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);

    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
```

Thank you for any hints.

Updated:

js function:

```
function getSelected(){
let payload = new Array()
let tblTickets = document.getElementById('tblTickets')
let checked = tblTickets.getElementsByTagName("input")
for (let i = 0; i < checked.length; i++) {
    if (checked[i].checked) {
        payload.push(checked[i].value)
    }
}
let numbers = []
if (payload.length > 0) {
    numbers = payload.map(Number)
    console.log(numbers)
}

const putMethod = {
    method : 'PUT',
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(numbers)
}
fetch(urlUpdate, putMethod)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);

    })
```

}

web.php:

```
Route::put("/tickets/update", [TicketsController::class, 'update'])->name('tickets.update');
```

Controller:

```
 public function update(Request $request): \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
{
    $request->validate([
        'ids' => ['required', 'array', 'min:1'],
        'ids.*' => ['integer']
    ]);
        $tickets = DB::connection('secondDb')->table('ticket')
            ->join('ticket_status', 'id', '=', 'status_id')
            ->whereIn('id', $request->input('ids'))
            ->update(['name' => 'Closed ']);


    return response()->json([
        'ticketsUpdated' => $tickets
    ]);

}
```

I still recieve two errors:
action.js:57 PUT http://mypath/tickets/update 419 (unknown status)
action.js:63 Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

I really cannot figure out how to pass my array, split it on numbers as id and update database. I have an build in update route for internal database. But for external I cannot use safe() and build in function provides with an id in route /bills/{id}, but I want to update a bunch of them, not one by one

Comment: Shouldn't the fetch method but `PUT` since that is what you've defined in your routes file? Also, just an FYI, you can specify the connection for a model using `on()` e.g. `Model::on('secondDB')`, or even create a new model and [set the connection explicitly](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#database-connections).

Comment: yes, my mistake. I was just playing with POST and PUT. It definetly should be PUT. However, my connection to DB is good. I can fetch GET data in console. But have problems with PUT. Can It be error with return status in PHP controller? I believe there is something wrong with my controller function which defines API call, but cannot figure out what exactly

Comment: const putMethod = {
        method : 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(numbers)
    }
    fetch(urlUpdate, putMethod)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error);

        })   I have this update. But it gives me an error in console action.js:57 PUT http://myRoute/update 419 (unknown status)

Comment: You're adding the ids to the body of the request but you're not retrieving them from the request in your controller. I can't tell from your code but it also doesn't look like you're providing a key for the ids so that you can retrieve them from the request in your controller either.

Answer (score 0):

First you use the `POST` method in your fetch request, while your route uses the `PUT` verb.
So you have to change the method specified in your fetch to `PUT`.

Here are some problems with your controller:

1. Your id array is in your request body and not as a parameter of the URL, so you need to adapt your controller action to use the Request.
2. You want to use a route with a list of id's to avoid making 1000 queries to the database, but you are doing exactly this because you are using a foreach and it is not optimized. You can use `whereIn()` instead.
3. Knowing that you are using fetch, prefer to return a JSON response rather than a view.

Here is a code example:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'ids' => ['required', 'array', 'min:1'],
        'ids.*' => ['integer']
    ]);

    $tickets = DB::connection('secondDB')->table('ticket')
            ->join('ticket_status', 'id', '=', 'status_id')
            ->whereIn('id', $request->input('ids'))
            ->update(['name' => 'Closed']);

    return response()->json([
      'ticketsUpdated' => $tickets;
    ]);
}
```

Comment: @Natalia If my answer helped you, please upvote. Remember to validate your request as I have shown and especially to use whereIn to drastically limit the number of queries to your database.

Answer (score 0):

Thx everyone. I found the solution to make it work without JS only Laravel

in blade:

```
 <form action="/tickets/update" method="POST">
 @csrf
 @method('PUT')

 @foreach($tickets as $ticket)

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input class="check" type="checkbox" id="{{$ticket->ticket_id}}" value="{{$ticket->ticket_id}}" name="ids[]" >
                    </td>
```

in controller:

```
 public function update(Request $request)
{
    $numbers = $request->input('ids');
    foreach ($numbers as $number)
    {
        $tickets = DB::connection('osdtbs')->table('ticket')
            ->where('ticket_id', '=', $number)
            ->update(['status_id' => '7']);
    }


    return redirect('/tickets');

}
```